# Artifact upload with NexusArtifactUploader failing with error for Maven project using Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, nexus

I am currently using Jenkins version 2.222.4, Nexus repository 3.X and NexusArtifactUploader jenkins plugin. **This all is on organisation's production.**

I have a maven project which I am able to build using jenkins pipeline. However, for uploading artifact I am having issue with NexusUploadArtifact plugin.

At the NexusUpload stage the pipeline is failing with below error.

**Error: Uploading file filename.jar failed**

I do not see any other error message which could have helped me to debug the issue.

I tried with two ways with NexusArtifactUploader plugin but ended with same error.

1. First way:

   ```
    stage('Upload Nexus Artifact') {
    steps {
        script {
            def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
            nexusArtifactUploader artifacts: [[artifactId: "${pom.artifactId}", classifier: '', file: "target/${pom.artifactId}-${pom.version}.${pom.packaging}", type: "${pom.packaging}"]], credentialsId: 'Here_Is_The_Creds', groupId: "${pom.groupId}", nexusUrl: 'nexus.something.com', nexusVersion: 'nexus3', protocol: 'http', repository: 'maven-snapshots', version: "${pom.version}"
        }
    }
   ```

   }
2. Second way

   stage('Upload Nexus Artifact') {
   steps {
   script {
   def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'

   ```
            nexusArtifactUploader(
                    nexusVersion: 'nexus3',
                    protocol: 'http',
                    nexusUrl: 'nexus.something.com',
                    groupId: "${pom.groupId}",
                    **version: "${pom.version}",**
                    repository: 'maven-snapshots',
                    credentialsId: 'Here_Is_The_Creds',
                    artifacts: [
                        [artifactId: "${pom.artifactId}",
                        file: "target/${pom.artifactId}-${pom.version}.${pom.packaging}",
                        type: "${pom.packaging}"]
                    ]
            )
        }
    }
   ```

When I read documentation of NexusUploadArtifact jenkins plugin, I learned that this plugin is not for artifacts generated by Maven project. Added snap and [url](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nexus-artifact-uploader/) for reference.

[image]

Many of the blogs outside stackoverflow and answers on stackoverflow suggested to use Sonatype Nexus Platform Plugin for Jenkins but in my case as I am on Jenkins 2.222.4, this plugin is not supported.

**I tried to replicate this on my local machine** but with latest version of Jenkins along with NexusArtifactUploader plugin and it did worked.

So, I am stuck on how can this be resolved. Can anyone help me on this as Jenkins version upgrade and Sonatype Nexus Platform Plugin are not the correct fit for me at this moment.

Thanks!

Comment: Why using an Jenkins plugin not using Maven itself for that  ... furthermore there is a need for an upgrade because 2.222.4 is a bit out of date...

Comment: @khmarbaise Agree, using maven build lifecycle like "clean deploy" will do but not sure how to integrate nexus credential in that case as there are lots of projects mapped to Jenkins and modifying settings.xml to add job specific nexus credential will further make things complicated. But in case you have some pointers to some reference to use just maven to deploy artifacts to nexus, please do share. Thanks!

Comment: Credentials beong to Jenkins in the credentials store which is used by config file provider plugin which handles the settings.xml ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update.

As mentioned and suggested by @khmarbaise, I was able to deploy artifacts to nexus with Maven without any plugin. Also, when I tried with maven, first I got complete error in Jenkins console about authentication then post correcting credentials I was able to upload artifact using Maven and using NexusArtifactUpload jenkins plugin. One issue / bug I found in NexusArtifactUpload jenkins plugin that, it intermittently do not show status of artifact upload on jenkins's console output log and that is the reason I decided to go with Maven.